# Windows WPF app rendering a collection of Circles with dynamic spacing,(not spacing)

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to render a variable sized collection of circles on my screen with an x-offset on them so they can be evenly spaced, and I can get them to render but they are all rendering ontop of each other,

I suspect this is something to do with how its reading my X and Y offsets, as my circles are changing color dynamically when I relaunch the app

xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window{
  public List<Citizen> Citizens { get; set; }
  private int numberOfCircles = 50; // Number of circles you want to display
  private double circleRadius = 20; // Fixed radius for all circles

  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      // Initialize the collection of citizens (circles)
      Citizens = new List<Citizen>();
  }

  private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var random = new Random();

      // Calculate Y-coordinate for all circles (bottom half of the screen)
      double yCoordinate = ActualHeight / 2;

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++)
      {
          // Calculate X-coordinate spacing between circles
          double xSpacing = ActualWidth / (numberOfCircles + 1);

          Citizens.Add(new Citizen
          {
              Radius = circleRadius,
              Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)random.Next(256), (byte)random.Next(256), (byte)random.Next(256))),
              X = i * xSpacing - circleRadius, // Adjust for circle radius
              Y = yCoordinate,
          });
      }

      // Set DataContext to 'this' to enable data binding
      DataContext = this;
  }
```

}

mainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Black" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <!-- Upper Section -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <!-- This row takes up the remaining available height -->
        <RowDefinition Height="2" />
        <!-- Divider (2 pixels high) -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <!-- Lower section -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Content for the Upper Section -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Blue">
        <!-- Replace with your content for the upper section -->
    </Border>

    <!-- White dividing bar -->
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <!-- Content for the Lower Section -->
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Green">
        <Grid>
            <!-- TextBlock in the lower section -->
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White">
                This is text in the lower section.<LineBreak/>
                It is vertically aligned to the top and horizontally aligned to the middle.
            </TextBlock>

            <!-- An ItemsControl to render the circles -->
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Citizens}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas  Background="Transparent" Width="{Binding ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight/2}"/>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" Height="{Binding Radius}" Fill="{Binding Color}"
                                 Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In order to enable automatic UI updates, better use a readonly ObservableCollection: `public ObservableCollection<Citizen> Citizens { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Citizen>();`

Comment: `Height="{Binding ActualHeight/2}"` will not work. It is pointless anyway to set the Width and Height of the ItemsPanel Canvas. Define a proper layout for the ItemsControl.